Gamma and Poisson distributions and their relations to the randomness
I'm reading the following paper:
https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article/32/1/122/1743683
and in Figure 3 (Section 4.4) the authors have shown some vertex degree distributions:
enter image description here
The above are vertex degree distributions $p(k)$ for some biological networks.
The authors claim that because the distribution of the measured degree distribution is a Gamma distribution and not a Poisson, thus the network is not random. But what's the reason behind the validity of this claim?
Is this claim from the paper correct: "A sufficient proof for the non-randomness of a graph is the significant deviation of the vertex degree distribution from the corresponding Poisson distribution."

The paper in question is not mathematical. Also, posts here should be mainly self-contained. Please edit it accordingly or, if that is impossible, please delete it.

As Iosif Pinelis mentioned, this question might be more suitable for another site, like https://stats.stackexchange.com/ . But to answer your question: both Poisson and Gamma distributions are random. The authors claim that the observed distribution of degrees sequences is not Poisson distributed (as one might naively expected from, e.g., an Erdos-Renyi model for a graph) but rather Gamma distributed.  They believe this because of the remarkably better fit as shown in the figures you attached.  (Their claim is visually obvious, so they don't bother with a statistical test for model selection.)

Seems to be a cross-post of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/653265/gamma-and-poisson-distributions-and-their-relations-to-the-randomness

@Statisticsstudent : It's not unusual to hear mathematicians using the word "random" to mean "uniformly distributed," although that's not what it means in standard definitions of the term "random variable."

Why are they showing graphs of Poisson probability mass functions that have expectations so much lower than the mean of the empirical distribution?

@Statisticsstudent : I'm not either, but I'm just saying sometimes the word "random" when used by mathematicians means something different from the sense that that word has in the term "random variable."

@MichaelHardy I meant how did you realize that "Why are they showing graphs of Poisson probability mass functions that have expectations so much lower than the mean of the empirical distribution?"

@Statisticsstudent : The mode of the Poisson distribution with expectation $\lambda$ is $$ \begin{cases} \lambda-1 & \text{unless $\lambda$ is an integer,} \ \text{both } \lambda-1 \text{ and } \lambda & \text{otherwise.}  \end{cases}$$ The mode of the gamma distribution proportional to $(\lambda x)^{\alpha-1} e^{-\lambda x} (\lambda , dx)$ for $x>0,$ which has expectation $\alpha/\lambda,$ is $(\alpha-1)/\lambda.$ So for both distributions, the mode is near the expectation. Now notice how different the modes are in the graphs that you see.
